# Need help, my only way of getting to school and work tomorrow!

Tags: honda, motorcycle, ignition, battery-drain, shadow

I've got a 1999 Honda Shadow 600, its been doing good recently and over the summer I put a good amount of work in it to keep it going.

I went to turn it on an it would sound like it would turn over but then the battery gave out. This has happened before so I would usually jump start it to get it going again. But today when I tried jumping it, it wouldn't turn over and idle. Eventually it just didn't give any power to the engine. I thought it may have been flooded so I just left it alone for a few hours.

I came back and tried starting it again but nothing. The dash and the lights were all working, but no power to the engine. I checked the main and ignition fuses and replaced both just in case but nothing still. Any thing seems weird?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: There's quite a few things that could be wrong, but it sounds like the battery could be shot. Beg or borrow a multi-tester and check the battery voltage.